# bash / linux - touch/mkdir from string in file

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, touch, mkdir

I have a file full of filenames and directory names. 
Example:

```
DIR,/mnt/sdcard/mydir1/
DIR,/mnt/sdcard/mydir2/
DIR,/mnt/sdcard/mydir3/
FILE,/mnt/sdcard/mydir1/file1.txt
FILE,/mnt/sdcard/mydir2/file1.txt
FILE,/mnt/sdcard/mydir3/file1.txt
```

with total around 30.000 entries of directories and filenames.
I need to create all the directories, sub-directories and files (empty ones) inside a specified folder. And I also want to skip all the directories/files that already exist!

Currently I have this, but I am hoping there is a better way, as this is very slow
and consumes a lot of CPU:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/mydir/dummydir/

for file in *.tree.txt; do

MEMBER=$(echo $file | cut -d '.' -f1)
DIRECTORY=/home/mydir/dummydir/$MEMBER

while read line
do

if [[ $line == FILE,* ]]
then

CUTOFFILE=$(echo "$line" | cut -c 6-)
touch "$DIRECTORY$CUTOFFILE"

else

CUTOFFDIR=$(echo "$line" | cut -c 5-)
if [[ ! -d "$DIRECTORY$line" && $line == DIR,* ]]; then
mkdir -p "$DIRECTORY$CUTOFFDIR"
fi


fi

done < $file
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/mydir/dummydir/

for file in *.tree.txt; do
    dir=${file%.tree.txt}

    while IFS=, read type path; do
        case $type in
            FILE) touch "$dir/$path";;
            DIR)  mkdir -p "$dir/$path";;
            *)    echo "bad line: $type,$path" >&2;;
        esac
    done < "$file"
done
```

I'm not a huge fan of `cut`, so I replaced it with other parsing methods.

- With each line containing two fields separated by a comma, you can cut out a lot of code by having `read` parse the line and store the two parts in separate variables. You can do that by temporarily overriding the `$IFS` variable with `IFS=,` which tells `read` to use `,` as the field separator. Then `read type path` reads the two parts into `$type` and `$path`.
- Both `touch` and `mkdir -p` are harmless when applied to files or directories that already exist, so you could probably omit the checks for existing files and just always do them.
- Since you start the script by `cd`ing to `/home/mydir/dummydir`, you don't really need to repeat that later.
- `${file%.tree.txt}` is a shorter way of stripping off `.tree.txt`. Another way is `$(basename "$file" .tree.txt)`.

Comment: That's very useful information right there. Small, efficient and simple. I was hoping it would improve the rate at which it created the files and folders, and here is what I got when I ran 'time' to compare them both;

./create_tree2.sh = real 0m29.650s 
 ./create_tree.sh = real 1m15.243s... Hats off, you've really helped me out :)

Comment: Btw, would pausing help out with CPU load?